# While loops with numbers in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

my code won't output what it should the instructions:
Read integers from input until an integer is read that is not in the range -20 to 25, both inclusive. Output the total number of integers read, including the integer that causes reading to stop. End with a newline.

Ex: If the input is -13 -49 -17 -16 -11, then the output is:

Number of integers read: 2
My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CountRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputValue;
        int countRead;

        inputValue = scnr.nextInt();
        countRead = 0;

        while ((inputValue >= -20) || (inputValue <= 25)) {
            countRead++;
            inputValue = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Number of integers read: " + (countRead + 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Think about this expression `(inputValue >= -20) || (inputValue <=  25)` What does `||` mean? Look at each of the two comparisons for 30. Which is true? Which is false? What happens after you apply `||` to those values? Should the final result be true or false for 30?

Comment: && instead of || thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this statement **very, very closely**:

```
while( (inputValue >= -20) || (inputValue <=  25)) {
```

And specifically what the while statement is evaluating;

```
((inputValue >= -20) || (inputValue <=  25))
```

If inputValue is say... `-49`, what does that expression evaluate to?  true for false?

Be careful!

Comment: && instead of || ...got it thanks!!!!